# Changing the order of elements in a std::array makes AVX code fail

Tags: c++, avx, avx2

I am currently writing a hashtable and one of my tests failed after changing some implementation to use vector extensions. Turns out that when I have a std::array (I do not know if it is a problem with std::array itself or something else) and insert elements in a certain order, my code does not work. But once I change the position of two elements, it suddenly works. The element in question is 33, once changed with 17, the code works as expected.

I have tried looking at the compiled assembly in godbolt, but my assembly is really not good enough to deduce any useful information from that.

I have written a minimal-reproducible code sample here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <immintrin.h>

int main() {
    // Dysfunctional order
    std::array<std::uint32_t, 8> keys_not_functional = {{1,17,33,49,0,0,0,0}};

    __m256i key_vector = _mm256_set1_epi32(33);
    __m256i cmp_vector = _mm256_loadu_si256(reinterpret_cast<const __m256i*>(keys_not_functional.data()));
    __m256i cmp = _mm256_cmpeq_epi32(key_vector, cmp_vector);

    std::uint8_t mask = _mm256_movemask_epi8(cmp);

    if (mask != 0) {
        std::uint8_t index = __builtin_ctz(mask) / 4;
        std::cout << "Found at in dysfunctional: " << unsigned(index) << std::endl;
    }

    // Changing 17 and 33 makes this work without a problem
    std::array<std::uint32_t, 8> keys_functional = {{1,33,17,49,0,0,0,0}};

    key_vector = _mm256_set1_epi32(33);
    cmp_vector = _mm256_loadu_si256(reinterpret_cast<const __m256i*>(keys_functional.data()));
    cmp = _mm256_cmpeq_epi32(key_vector, cmp_vector);

    mask = _mm256_movemask_epi8(cmp);

    if (mask != 0) {
        std::uint8_t index = __builtin_ctz(mask) / 4;
        std::cout << "Found at in functional: " << unsigned(index) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it with: `g++ -std=c++17 -mavx2 -march=native -O0`. Running on gcc 7.4.0 in WSL1, Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, kernel 4.4.0-18362-Microsoft. My Processor is a Kaby Lake R i5-8250.

I have not tried compiling it on a different system yet. Is this a problem with my configuration/system or even WSL? Can someone point me to the reason for this?

Comment: `_mm256_movemask_epi8` return 32 bits. If you store that into an `uint8_t` obviously information may get lost.

Comment: Yeah that absolutely makes sense. From intuition I though that the signature means it returns an 8-bit number, but it does not. Thank you.